# How to use the Windows API in MinGW?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

How to use the [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) in [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)?

Answer (score 24):

Whenever I've done this, I just

```
#include <windows.h>
```

and start coding. MinGW comes with a `windows.h` file so you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: It is wrong to tell that MinGW comes with windows.h. People like me, who prefers copying latest packages and building MinGW by yourself (not using installer), should copy w32api package from MinGW download site.

Comment: my mingw has that header file, but it fails to link

Answer (score 8):

I occasionally use the Windows API for Qt apps that I build using Qt Creator/MinGW - I just `#include` the appropriate Windows SDK header (the headers come with MinGW) and it just works.  However, you may need to `#define` a few things in order that some API calls are exposed.  For example, I recently needed to call `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` (found in `shlobj.h`) but needed to define `_WIN32_IE` to `0x0400` first.

Comment: The need to `#define _WIN32_IE` is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#macros-for-conditional-declarations).

Answer (score 4):

In case if you installed MinGW as a part of [MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/) on Windows then you can install `Windows.h` and other Win-API headers through following command inside MSYS shell:

`pacman -S msys2-w32api-headers msys2-w32api-runtime`

then header is located in

`c:/MSYS_PATH/usr/include/w32api/windows.h`

also you can search any package name (or sub-name) through e.g.

`pacman -Ss w32api`

---

If you're on Linux then `Windows.h` can be installed through

`sudo apt install mingw-w64-common`

then header is located here

`/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h`

you may probably need to include compiler's option

`-I/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/`