# How to concatenate two strings with C and MinGW?

Tags: c, string, winapi, mingw

How do I concatenate (or even assign) two strings (`TCHAR` arrays, I guess) in MinGW with GCC?

- `StrCatBuff`?
  `#include <shlwapi.h>` and `-lshlwapi` do work, but you're [not supposed to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- `_tcscat`?
  Seems not to exist
- [`StringCchCat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  Seems not to exist. `strsafe.h` doesn't exist.

The same holds true for their respective assignment functions like `StringCchCpy` and `_tcscpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_tcscat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx) (or the "secure" version, [`_tcscat_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx)) works just fine for concatenating arrays of `TCHAR`s. You have to include `tchar.h` in order to use either of these functions.

The same should be true for `StringCchCat`, which as you mention is defined in `strsafe.h`.

If you're missing these header files, make sure that you've installed the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279). It's probably not included by default with MinGW like it is with Microsoft's tooling.

Comment: Allright, I just installed half a GB just for some string functions. Now, how do I make MinGW aware of it?

Comment: @AndreKR: No idea. That information should be in the documentation for your development tools. Or perhaps can be found in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549123/how-to-use-the-windows-api-in-mingw).

Comment: It's even worse. My program doesn't compile any longer: `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to WinMain@16`

Comment: @AndreKR: `WinMain` is not the correct name for the entry point in Unicode builds. The function is named `wWinMain` in that case. You can also use the `_tWinMain` macro (defined in `tchar.h`) to automatically choose the correct entry point name. Make sure that the `lpCmdLine` parameter is defined as type `LPTSTR` so that it matches the definition of the function in the headers.

Comment: Hm, somehow it compiles again. Using wWinMain didn't work, probably because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw. As for strsafe.h, it still doesn't find it.

Comment: @AndreKR: Strange. Sounds like MinGW is completely broken. This is only one of the many reasons I don't use it. I'd give up and download Visual Studio Express instead.

Comment: I did. Continuation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198787/how-do-i-compile-a-window-api-program-using-cl ;)