# Which header file loads the DLLs in Win32 api?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

For example, to call MessageBox all I need is to include windows.h, so I assume some header file does the actual LoadLibrary.

How does this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows header file that declares `MessageBox` declares it but does not define it. In other words, the header file merely declares that there is a function with a particular prototype that is defined somewhere else.

The definition is provided by an import library. For `MessageBox`, that import library is `user32.lib`. That import library is passed to the linker and provides the definition.

The actually loading of the Windows DLL that implements `MessageBox`, user32.dll is done by the loader. The linker emits an executable file that contains metadata declaring the dependent DLLs, and the functions that must be imported. That's the PE import table. At process load time, the loader reads the import table, loads dependent DLLs, and resolves the references.

Comment: Thanks... How does the linker know which lib file is needed?

Comment: You tell it which libraries to link as arguments that are passed to the linker. Look in the linker options in the vs config

Comment: @user2263786:  This question can help fill in some details:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198787

Comment: Thanks again, last one: I see a list of lib files in the vs config, does the linker link all of them or it searches for the libs I actually use?

Comment: It just links the functions that you call in your program