# Using InitiateSystemShutdown() function under C++ and Qt Framework

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

I would like to use the [InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in C++ with MinGW.

How can I load `Advapi32.dll` and call the function `InitiateSystemShutdown`?

Comment: I removed the reference to Qt as it did not seem relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549123/how-to-use-the-windows-api-in-mingw

Comment: So, when i am right, including winreg.h ist enough to use this function?

Comment: Winreg.h simply defines the function. You have to link to Advapi32.lib so the linker knows where to find the function.

Comment: @Remy The header file *declares* the function. The import library *defines* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873.aspx) section of the documentation contains the information:

> **Header**: Winreg.h (include Windows.h)
>
> **Library**: Advapi32.lib

So you must include `Windows.h` to have the function declared. And you must link with `Advapi32.lib` to have the function defined.

Comment: Use the `-l` option: `-lAdvapi32`