# Compiling a DLL which uses CString in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, mingw

I am using MinGW compiler in Qt.

I have this error message

> 'CString' has not been declared

when compiling a DLL, which uses `CString` datatype in the class member function. Here is a section from the header file :

```
#include <windows.h>
class someClass
{
// Construction
public:
    bool loadimagefile(CString filename);
    bool loadtextfile(CString filename, int nFileSize);
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx), I should include `altstr.h` to use `CString`, but this is not provided in MinGW...

I have also tried this ([How to use the Windows API in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549123/how-to-use-the-windows-api-in-mingw)), but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't really expect to do that, passing C++ objects across a module boundary. Use `const wchar_t*` instead.

Comment: @jacaheyo, which CString do you want to use? MFC version? Then you should link MFC. But probably using POD types is a bit simplier.

Comment: MFC and ATL are part of Visual Studio. You cannot use them with any other development environment.

Comment: Yes, the `CString` is from MFC.
Thank you all, from what I understand now, the only way is to link MFC.. I was hoping that I didn't have to install the Windows SDK or Visual Studio..